# Locate where is the nth occurrence of a token in a string separated by pipes

Tags: regex, db2, db2-400

I'm I am a newbie with Regex and would like to know if it is possible to do that.

It is possible to locate the token position of a sub-string in a string like the below sample text?

```
AA|BBBBBBBBBB|XXXX||XXXX||FFFFFFFFFFF
```

Requesting the position of the 1st occurrence of 'XXXX' I must get '3', requesting the 2nd occurrence of 'XXXX' I must get '5', requesting the 3rd occurrence of 'XXXX' I must get '0' cause there's no a 3rd ocurrence.

This can be done using just regex?

Thanks in advance.

PS: If it is possible I will implement this solution on DB2 v7r2 using REGEX functions to replace an UDF I write long time ago on PLSQL to do this job.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Split the string? [What is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how'd I'd normally use regex....

But it can get the job done...

```
create variable mysource varchar(50)         
    default('AA|BBBBBBBBBB|XXXX||XXXX||FFFFFFFFFFF');


select                                   
 regexp_count(                           
      substring(mysource                 
               , 1                       
               ,regexp_instr(mysource    
                            ,'XXXX'      
                            ,1
                            ,2  --occurance
                            ,1)      
               )                         
      ,'\|')                             
from sysibm.sysdummy1;

REGEXP_COUNT
           5
```

Might need to concat a `'|'` to the end of the source if it's possible for the pattern to fall in the last position.

**EDIT**

Ok, here's a completely different way...using a recursive common table expression (RCTE)

Note that the solution is easiest if you ensure that the text ends with a delimiter...

```
create variable mysource varchar(50)         
    default('AA|BBBBBBBBBB|XXXX||XXXX||FFFFFFFFFFF|');
```

And the code..

```
with splitstring (pos, data, remain) as (           
  select 1                                          
   , substring(mysource,1,locate('|', mysource) -1 )
   , substring(mysource,locate('|', mysource) + 1 ) 
  from sysibm.sysdummy1                             
union all                                           
  select pos + 1                                    
   , substring(remain,1,locate('|', remain) -1 )    
   , substring(remain,locate('|', remain) + 1 )     
, matches as (                                      
select row_number() over (order by pos) as occur    
       ,pos                                         
from splitString                                    
where data = 'XXXX'                                 
)                                                   
select coalesce(pos,0) as pos           
from sysibm.sysdummy1            
    left join matches 
     on occur = 2   ;
```

Results

```
   POS
     5
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles! Good approach, but that doesn't work. With your solution it you look for 'X' you obtain the same response as trying to locate 'XXXX'

Comment: @PedroVaquero...if you sometimes search for XXXX and sometimes for X, then you'd need to include the separators in your search...I'll try to find some time to edit the answer.

Comment: note that | is a special character in regex...going to need to escape it...'\|'